# pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file on m1 Mac running Mac os Monteray

Tags: python, macos, pygame, macos-monterey

I've looked around but haven't found any solutions that work.

I'm just learning pygame using the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO6qQDNa2UY&list=WL&index=44&t=1379s

but when I try to link the image I get the error: pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file.

I've tried everything short of reinstalling pygame again (previous issue), or reinstalling python.

Here is my code

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)

FPS = 60

YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png')).convert()
RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_red.png')).convert()

def draw_window():
    WIN.fill((RED))
    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (300,100))
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        
        draw_window()
    pygame.QUIT()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to load `spaceship_yellow.png` and `spaceship_red.png` which judging from extensions are `PNG`s not `BMP`s, your error

```
pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file
```

suggest that pygame is expecting `BMP` file. [pygame.image docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) says

> The image module is a required dependency of pygame, but it only
> optionally supports any extended file formats. By default it can only
> load uncompressed BMP images. When built with full image support, the
> `pygame.image.load()` function can support the following formats.

then enumarate formats, apparently you do not have full image support, I think simplest solution is to convert `PNG`s you have to uncompressed `BMP` image format.

Answer (score 0):

Turning the image to a BMP does work but I would rather still have the full functionality of pygame. What I did to finally make it work was from a thread [here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2458). I put this in the terminal to get it working:

```
python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/nelsonlove/pygame.git
```

This will update your pygame to version 2.0.2.dev1, modified for m1 Mac.