# Failing to get pygame running under M1

Tags: python, pygame, homebrew, apple-m1

I tried to install the pygame module and Homebrew described [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-install-Pygame-on-a-MacBook-M1?share=1).

By installing venvdotapp, I get the Error Message:

```
Sorry your Python wasn't build with --enable-Framework
```

I think I can ignore that if I use a VENV, which `Pycharm` does..

By running Pycharme with pygame I get this Error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from pygame.base import * # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I'm confused about that and don't know how to fix.

Comment: This post is M1 specific. I had problems to install pygame at Mac Intel but by adding the module inside Pycharme, works well.
So, if I run the Intel Version of Pycharme, I can work with it but not if I use the AArch64 Version of Pycharme, which is a lot faster.
So this is why I posted the "special" install Routine in my first post, but as I reported, venvdotapp installation don't work and Pycharme spits out those bones...

Comment: tysm for the answer. I am also sorry because I don't have much idea of what your question specifically ask for , I thought you were have problem installing pygame on mac. I will recommend it best for you to ask the person who made the instructions u followed : https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-install-Pygame-on-a-MacBook-M1?share=1 .   @Karl-Heinz Skywalker

Comment: Yes ist is a problem getting pygame run... with a M1 machine.
By failing around I came a little bit further by installing pygame via Pycharm inside the Project venv but now pygame won't except png files, just bmp which should be related by the PIL / PILLOW (Python image library) pkg but they seemed to be installed correctly...

Comment: Ok, I found the same problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972133/pygame-error-file-is-not-a-windows-bmp-file-on-m1-mac-running-mac-os-monteray

Comment: Did it answer your question?